# how to set page to print the whole text and image inside richtextbox

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have problem to print all the item inside richtextbox. here is my code for printing.

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim PrintDocument1 As New Printing.PrintDocument
    Dim PrintSettings1 As New Printing.PrinterSettings
    Dim PrintPreview1 As New PrintPreviewDialog

    PrintDocument1.PrinterSettings.PrintRange = Printing.PrintRange.AllPages
    AddHandler PrintDocument1.PrintPage, AddressOf PrintDocument1_PrintPage
    'Set the printer name.
    PrintDocument1.PrinterSettings.PrinterName = PrintSettings1.PrinterName


    PrintPreview1.Document = PrintDocument1
    PrintPreview1.ShowDialog()


End Sub

Private Sub PrintDocument1_PrintPage(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Drawing.Printing.PrintPageEventArgs) Handles PrintDocument1.PrintPage

    Dim intX, intTotal, intA, intB, heightImg, heightText1, heightText2, heightText3, heightText4, heightBlank As Integer


    Dim randNum, Sum As Integer
    randNum = 1000
    intTotal = 0

   If ComboBox1.Text = "AE" Then
        For intA = 1 To Convert.ToInt32(TextBox2.Text)
            Sum = randNum + intA
            For intX = 1 To 8

                Dim SumAE As String = "AE-" & Sum.ToString

                Dim font As New Font("Arial", 8, FontStyle.Regular)
                e.Graphics.DrawString("TEMPORARY MRN - HOSPITAL  ", font, Brushes.Black, 10, heightText1 + 10)
                e.Graphics.DrawString(SumAE, font, Brushes.Black, 10, heightText2 + 20)

                AxBarcode1.Text = SumAE
                AxBarcode1.Refresh()

                Dim img As Image = AxBarcode1.Picture

                Dim orgData = Clipboard.GetDataObject
                Clipboard.SetImage(img)
                Me.RichTextBox1.Paste()

                e.Graphics.DrawImage(Clipboard.GetImage, 10, heightImg + 30)
                e.Graphics.DrawString("  Name  : ", font, Brushes.Black, 10, heightText3 + 110)
                e.Graphics.DrawString("  IC  : ", font, Brushes.Black, 10, heightText4 + 120)
                e.Graphics.DrawString("", font, Brushes.Black, 10, heightBlank + 150)

                heightImg = heightImg + 150
                heightText1 = heightText1 + 150
                heightText2 = heightText2 + 150
                heightText3 = heightText3 + 150
                heightText4 = heightText4 + 150
                heightBlank = heightBlank + 150

                intTotal += intX
            Next intX

            intB += intA
        Next intA
    End If
End Sub
```

The page preview only 1 page. It should more because there is a 8times loop based on value inserted in textbox2.

[image]

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks :)